# send data from form with $('#frmadata').serializeArray return raw html code

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax

My problem is about sending data from element input form with ajax [ serializeArray() ], but no luck because the parse_str() always retun NULL value , but actualy the data are existed

so I am  new with PHP thing and I have searched over the internet about this Problem. The result isn't specific with my case right now.

this just one page of code and running under PHP 8.2

the structure of code like a common input form , there's a table with 3 elements input and 1 submit button, course the ids for each element. its wrap with form tag too and the id is 'frmdata'.

well in short,  the form and js validation work fine, when the input empty the pop up show.

after the last condition is else , where all the input are fill up

```
let data = $('#frmdata').serializeArray();
```

right after above line Trying figure out what content inside variabel [first alert] :

```
 alet(data);
```

the alert message return like this :** [object:object],[object:object],[object:object] **
is this normal ? the message not returning  the value that we type in those 3 element.

[image: alerting content of serializeArray]

next line is inside ajax block I'm write like below[second alert] :

```
 $.ajax ({
    url:"tes.php",
    method:"post",
    data:{'data':$.param(data)},
   success:function(data) {
   
         alert(data);
         window.location.reload();
   
       }
   
   });
```

for the 2nd alert the content is just raw html code.
[image: alerting param data]

with those problem above , the parse_str() syntaks always show NULL value

Adding some imformation about the ptoblem .

So when the ajax send data to php, i write below code

```
<?php
   
 If(isset($_POST)) {
      
     $_POST = parse_str($_POST['data'],$_POST);
     
     echo'<pre>';
     print_r($_POST);
     exho'</pre>;
     die();
 }
 
?>
```

than the browser return null value

[image: tje parsing object failed, returning null]

Comment: `is this normal`...yes that's what JS displays when you try to visualise an object or array. It's not text, so JS can't know exactly how you wanted it to appear on the screen

Comment: The simplest way to send form data to the server for processing normally using jQuery is to use [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/). Then if you send that to PHP in a POST request, all the serialised fields will be available in the $_POST array, just like if you'd submitted it with a regular form. You didn't show how you are currently trying to read the data in PHP when it is received from the AJAX request, but this is the standard approach.

Comment: `Trying figure out what content inside variabel`...use `console.log` instead. `alert` is for showing messages to the user, not for debugging!

Comment: `the parse_str() syntaks`... it's not clear what you're talking about here, because you didn't show the relevant code or data. Always provide a [mre] of your issue, and try to focus on a single issue at a time in your code. See also [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: All major browsers have developer tools nowadays. Rather that printing server response in an `alert()`, just look at it in the "Response" pane of the "Network" pane.

Comment: @ADyson im adding some information about parsing object array to php, but its returning null. Im using android phone , its limited feature on browser so there is no developer thing to use like console.log etx.. thanks..

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález yes im aware about that, but for some reason im just using android phone with php and webserver inside , the browser juat had a limited feature. There is no developer tools in mobile version . Thanks

Comment: You don't need parse_str. Just change `data:{'data':$.param(data)}` to `data: $('#frmdata').serialize()` in the $.ajax request code, and remove this line: `$_POST = parse_str($_POST['data'],$_POST);`. And then try again. You are making a simple task a lot more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: @ADyson it's work with serialize(); and you right i'm making it hard .lol , i gotta learn more about the fundamental thing in php. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to send form data to the server for processing normally using jQuery is to use [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/). Then if you send that to PHP in a POST request, all the serialised fields will be available in the `$_POST` array, just like if you'd submitted it with a regular form.

Therefore you don't need `parse_str`, or `serializeArray` or `$.param`. You are making it more complicated than it needs to be.

Just change

```
data:{'data':$.param(data)}
```

to data:

```
$('#frmdata').serialize()
```

in the `$.ajax` request code, and remove this line:

```
$_POST = parse_str($_POST['data'],$_POST);
```